# Is separate validation and test set needed when training SVM?

Tags: svm

Given a set of features extracted from a training dataset which are used to train a SVM.
The SVM parameters (e.g. c, gamma) are chosen using k-folds cross validation e.g. the training dataset is divided into 5 folds, with one chosen as validation set. Rotation of folds is done and the average accuracy used to choose the best parameters.
So then should I have another set (Test set) and report (as in paper publication) the results on this ? My understanding is that since the validation set was used to choose the parameters, the Test set is required.
In machine learning, the Test set is something not seen until we have decided on the classifier (e.g. in competitions, the test set is unknown and we submit our final classifier based only on the training set).

Answer (score 0):

The common approach is that after the cross validation phase, you would need to tune your parameters further and hence the need of a validation set to control the quality of each model.

Once you have a model that you believe can't be improved significantly over the validation set without risk of over-fitting, then you use your model over the test set to report results.

EDIT:

Since you are specifically asking about k-fold cross-validation, the technique implicitly separates a model for testing the resulted model, hence there is no need for an extra test step.

From the wikipedia article:

"Of the k subsamples, a single subsample is retained as the validation data for testing the model, and the remaining k − 1 subsamples are used as training data"
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#k-fold_cross-validation)

Comment: I have come across quite a number of papers where the average results from k-fold cross validation are reported, without any test set results, ie. the last step you mentioned (use model over the test set) was not performed.

Comment: @ng0323 Sorry I didn't read the k-fold the first time I read your question. k-fold cross validation actually separates one of the subsets to do what I described, so they are actually doing it implicitly and don't need an extra test step.